# Safari Top Sites thumbnails are not logged in

Tags: mac, safari

The thumbnails on Top Sites page in Safari are generated as if I'm not logged in on these sites. For instance, I'm logged in on Facebook but the thumbnail displays the Facebook login page.

Is there a way to fix that?

I'm using Safari 5.2 and OS X 10.7.3. As I remember I had the same problem with Safari 5.1.

*Update*: I just noticed that it only applies to https:// sites, such as Facebook or Twitter. http:// works fine, I can see the updated picture for YouTube for example.

Answer (score 0):

This is by design. Safari does this in the event that someone OTHER THAN you were to use your computer, they would not see personal / secure data that would otherwise appear on those sites.

Comment: If someone else were to use my computer they could just click on any link in Top Sites and get ALL my secure data from this site.

Comment: Yep. Yet there are cases where folks don't save their info / sessions, albeit very few. Just a hunch that Apple is being "safe" rather than sorry :/